# Roberta Tokenization of multiple sequences

Tags: huggingface-transformers

The [Roberta Tokenizer](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/41750a6cff55e401364568868d619747de3db037/src/transformers/tokenization_roberta.py#L154) in huggingface-transformers describes Roberta's tokenization
method as such:

```
- single sequence: ``<s> X </s>``
- pair of sequences: ``<s> A </s></s> B </s>``
```

I'm curious why the tokenization of multiple sequences is not `<s> A </s><s> B </s>`?

Building upon the above, if I were to encode more than two sequences manually, should I encode them as `<s> A </s></s> B </s></s> C </s>` or as `<s> A </s><s> B </s><s> C </s>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with many other questions, this can probably be best answered by "because it has been pretrained that way".

The main benefit of models in the transformer family is the insane amount of pretraining that goes into them. Unless you are willing to replicate the weeks/months of that pretraining stage, I think it is best to accept the feature as it comes.

Related to this, it also implies that your suggested approach of feeding in more than two sentences at a time probably won't work, see [this](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/65) related issue; since RoBERTa is not trained to accept input of more than two sentences, it might not work without having a very large pretraining dataset.

I think for more implementation-specific details, you should probably also head over to the huggingface issue tracker itself, this sounds like a promising feature that others might be interested to work on/use for themselves. But keep in mind that the token limit stays the same, and 512 tokens is not much for three or more sentences...